# A question in printing every other letter (like A,C,E) from a string (ABCDEFG) in a for loop

Tags: swift, string, modulo

How do I create a for-in loop that will loop through the characters of alphabet, and print every other letter by continuing to the next iteration if you are on a letter you do not wish to print?

My code is:

```
let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

for letter in alphabet  {
    if letter % 2 {
        continue
    }
    print(letter)
}
```

It is not working.

I tried to run it, but it did not work. I tried Index but that did not work.

Comment: "It is not working" - what exactly is not working?

Comment: @koen Character is not an integer. You can't use the modulo operator

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `enumerated` and filter on the index

```
for (index, letter) in alphabet.enumerated() where index.isMultiple(of: 2) {
    print(letter)
}
```

Or a more traditional loop

```
var doPrint = true
for letter in alphabet {
    if doPrint { print(letter)}
    doPrint.toggle()
}
```

Comment: your second approach is just a variation of what I suggested